# Freeform Pro v4.0.12 Filtering Issues

Tags: solspace-freeform

Using EE v2.6.1 MSM
Freeform Pro v4.0.12

When login EE CP using Chrome or Firefox – Under FreeForm Pro Entries listing, when filter using the search keywords or filter selection it kick you out of EE and required to login again.

Is this an error on FreeForm Pro or is this new version functionality? Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that was fixed in Freeform 4.1.0: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/change_log/#v4.1.0